# How to modify TaskDialog's Show() call to be blocking and return a value when closed?

Tags: c#, windows-7, taskdialog

I'm using the WindowsAPICodePack's TaskDialog implementation, but it bugs me that I have to listen to click handlers on its buttons for even the more basic implementations. I'd like to convert/wrap it so that like the old MessageBox it blocks until closed and then returns a value based on what was done. Is there anything I can read for the basics on how to do this? I just have no idea where to even start, as I am admittedly not that familiar with the Win32 underpinnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it helps someone, after some reading I figured out that the Show call is blocking already. In order to return a value, I implemented a base class `ExtendedTaskDialog<T>` which contains a `TaskDialog` and contains a helper `Show(Window)` method in order to assign the TaskDialog's parent, and an abstract `public T Show(Window)` method. Actual dialogs derive from this, and derive their own enum to supply as the base type, like `MyDialog : ExtendedTaskDialog<MyDialogResult>`. Then, internally, `MyDialog`'s buttons' Click handlers set the result before calling the `Close` method of the the internal `TaskDialog`.